# Invalid VSTS Check-in Status

Tags: build, azure-devops

Using VS 2017 at 15.8.3 with VSTS for source control.

Upon submitting changes it uses a defined build and displays the "Build Request - XXX" page for build notification.

Recently, I've been getting an error on the page at job end that states Build Request - XXX -- Check-in Rejected (see images). Which is not true, the check-in has been performed by the build process and the shelveset is deleted.

[Build Response Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iizvH.png)

[Log From Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nmk4.png)

Comment: What's the changes did you make for the gated checkin? And can you click the Check In button in VS, even though it shows Build Request - XXX -- Check-in Rejected? Besides, can you show the details build logs here? And at which step it shows "Deleted shelveset xxx"?

Comment: I changed the Build Number format from $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r) to $(date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(rev:.r). I tried changing it back but no joy!

Comment: There must be some changes on the MS side as the build email has changed

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the Label Sources task not completing successfully in the build. This is caused by using variables within the Get Sources Mappings, e.g., $/Project/$(BuildBranch) This is detailed at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60764/label-sources-does-not-work-when-using-variables-i.html.

The above reference indicted that this issue was fixed, and it was as this only recently reappeared in my builds.

Comment: I suspect this is a regression error caused by the switch to Azure DevOps changes.